# Dimension of space of Eisenstein series $\mathcal{E}_k(\Gamma)$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, modular-forms

Let $\Gamma$ be a congruence subgroup of $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$, and define the space of  Eisenstein series for $\Gamma$ to be $\mathcal{E}_k(\Gamma):=\{f\in M_k(\Gamma)\colon \langle f,S_k(\Gamma)\rangle_\Gamma=0\}$, the orthogonal complement of $S_k(\Gamma)$ in $M_k(\Gamma)$ with respect to the petersson inner product.  Then I want to show a dimension bound of $$
\dim\mathcal{E}_k(\Gamma)\leq\#\text{Cusp}(\Gamma),
$$
by constructing an element in $\mathcal{E}_k(\Gamma)$ for each cusp in $\text{Cusp}(\Gamma)$. However, I don't see how I can use cusps to cook up new Eisenstein series. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If I remember my modular forms correctly, whenever you have more Eisenstein series than cusps, then some linear combination of them will tend to zero at each of the cusps, which is the defining characteristic of a cusp form, hence must be identically $0$. Thus the dimension of the space of Eisenstein series cannot exceed the number of cusps.

Answer (score 2):

$$SL_2(\Bbb{Z})i\infty = \bigcup_{j=1}^m \Gamma \alpha_j i\infty$$
where the union is disjoint and $\alpha_j\in SL_2(\Bbb{Z})$. The RHS are the cusps.

The map $$M_k(\Gamma) \to \Bbb{C}^m, f\to (f|_k \alpha_1 i\infty,\ldots,f|_k \alpha_m i\infty)$$ is $\Bbb{C}$-linear with kernel $S_k(\Gamma)$.

Thus $$\dim_\Bbb{C}(E_k(\Gamma))=\dim_\Bbb{C}(M_k(\Gamma)/S_k(\Gamma))\le m$$

For many $k$ and $\Gamma$ it is a strict inequality (not for the normal subgroups $\Gamma=\Gamma(n)$ and $k\ge 4$ even)

Comment: Are you sure the RHS of your first equation are indeed the cusps? In general, the number $m$ is equal to the index $(\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}\colon\Gamma)$, which is greater or equal to the number of cusps, since there is a canonical surjection $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})\backslash \Gamma\to\text{Cusp}(\Gamma)$?

Comment: You are confusing $SL_2(\Bbb{Z})i\infty = \bigcup_{j=1}^m \Gamma \alpha_j i\infty$ with $SL_2(\Bbb{Z}) = \bigcup_{j=1}^r \Gamma \alpha_j $ @James The stabilizer of $i\infty$ is $z\to z+n$.